# authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 535, response: 5.7.0 ...authentication rejected)]

Tags: php, email

When i execute my php script, it gives me an error

> authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 535, response: 5.7.0 ...authentication rejected)]

Here is my  php script, i am sure that password and username are correct

```
 $from="postmaster";
$headers = array ('From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject
);


$host="ssl://smtp.aruba.it";
$port="465";
$username="info@****.com";
$password="*****";


$body = $mime -> get();
$headers = $mime -> headers($headers);

$smtp= Mail::factory('smtp',array('host'=>$host, 'port'=>$port,'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));


$query="SELECT * from payment where iduser='$iduser'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row['amount'] > 0)

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
 }
```

Comment: Your host should be just the domain, no `ssl://` in front of it.

Comment: @aynber i have tried but it is the same error

Comment: You will need to talk to your smtp host to verify your credentials. "Authentication rejected" says that your host doesn't like them.

Comment: `i am sure that password and username are correct` The error message means your host disagrees

Comment: remove the ssl://  from the host and test your username password here `http://webmail.aruba.it/`  to ensure it's correct

Answer (score 0):

Google have to allow your app to use your own account, to allow this google provided an easy way, just go to https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha, then click continue, then with 10 min, use your application to try to send email again, and google will remember the application/service and allow your application to access your account as long as you don't change your password.